# Using Mathematica CDF for publishing?

Tags: publishing

I have a quick question on publishing. What do the community think about CDF technology of MAthematica. I am rather interested in using this technology for publishing short articles on a website. Do you find it good? Annoying? Better a pdf file written in Latex? I would appreciate opinions. The interactivity of the technology seems nice (from the examples I saw). Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Use MathJax ( http://www.mathjax.org ).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching from Mathematica to MATLAB: As a text editor?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439278/switching-from-mathematica-to-matlab-as-a-text-editor)